# MetadataAPI Remote Site Setting and Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, connected-apps, migration, remote-site-settings

An instance migration is planned next week for our SF org. We have a marketing cloud business unit which is connected to it.

As part of our preparation for the migration we followed the instructions in [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000322257&type=1)  regarding modifying remote site settings of MetadataAPI site. We've noticed that currently Remote Site URL of this site is not configured properly (the URL is using our previous SF instance instead of the current one). However, we do not notice any functionality of MC connect which isn't working because of that, nor any issues with the MC<>SF integration. **Does anyone can provide info or documentation regarding how this MetadataAPI site settings affects the integration with MC or how it is related to MC?**

Many thanks,
Barak